# importing Xlsx file into sql database

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, connection-string

I want to import an XLSX file into sql database. If I use this connection string

```
 string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;""", openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

Ijust can import Xls file , what should I do to import the Xlsx file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guide help 
http://www.ashishblog.com/importexport-excel-xlsx-or-xls-file-into-sql-server/

you need Data Connectivity Components  for the xlsx file download driver of your version of office